# Convert Object to 2D array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can we convert an Object to a 2D Array,

My Object is like this

[image]

So That Array Key will be  like 'STARS_2' and value is ["STARS_4", "STARS_0", "STARS_12"]

with My attempts I can get something like this,
[image]

With this Code,

```
 var testArray =[];

            _.map(childFieldNames, function (value, key) {
                var newArray = new Array();
                newArray[key] = value;
                testArray.push(newArray);
            });
```

Here Keys are actually another array, which I do not want. I want key should be like 'STARS_2' , i.e. property of master object.

Comment: "Array key will be like STARS_2..." surely this would make it an Object which is already what you have. Arrays can only have numeric keys....??

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
var ary2D = Object.keys(childFieldNames).map(function (key) {
    return childFieldNames[key];
});
```

Comment: it does most of the stuff , just need to add 'Keys' in ary2D , currently it just a new Array ..

Comment: As Adam says above, if you add the keys into the 2D array, you end up with, your original object again. Or do you mean that you want the keys to be another array as well inside your ary2D? Could you clarify your desired result?

Comment: Ohh, now I got it. All I want to get the value when I have a key like 'STARS_2' (as string) , I cant do that with my current object

Comment: Hmmm. If you use yourObject['STARS_2'], you will get the array corresponding to the 'STARS_2' key in your object?

Answer (score 1):

better version for what Shilly showed would be:

```
const arr2D = Object.values(childFieldNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.entries(obj)
```

E.g.

```
const objVariable = {name: "Ted", job: "Dentist"}

const 2dArray = Object.entries(objVariable)

console.log(2dArray) // will print [["name", "Ted"], ["job", "Dentist"]]
```

Object.entries is a static method that belongs to the Object class. As a parameter, it accepts an object and returns a two-dimensional array.

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score -1):

You don’t need to create your structure into 2D array to just iterate over each key and its respective value(which is an array). If you want to iterate over it you can do something like this.

```
const object = {
  a: [1,2,3],
  b: [2,3,5]
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
  value.forEach(v=>{
      console.log(`${key}: ${v}`);
  })
}
```